# android new intent error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am new on android und I try  to transfer data between two Activities.
Eclipse tell me that the line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, PostDataActivity.class);
```

Constructor Intent is undefined. What can I do?

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ansehen);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // create class object
                gps = new GpsData(StartActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    String mlat = String.valueOf(latitude);

                    // \n is for new line
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, PostDataActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
```

Comment: try `Your_activityName.this` instead only `this` and have you added `StartActivity(i);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to initialize your Intent from inside an `OnClickListener`. Hence, the `this` parameter you are passing to your constructor refers to the listener, and not your Activity.

To fix the problem use :

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, PostDataActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
    Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, PostDataActivity.class);
```